# Output image URL from image object as background-image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, syntax

I have a field group that loads an image into an image object, however I'm trying to output the url into a style background-image parameter. It's outputting the URL but in a way that the style sheet can't pick up.

```
<? $test_output .= '<div class="complete-image cropped" style="background-image: url("'. $smallimage .'");">'."\n";?>
```

I'm returning test_output at the end correctly, is this a problem with the syntax?

Comment: Can you please provide example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a problem with the syntax?

Not a PHP syntax error but a HTML! the second double quote after `url(` will end the value of `style` attribute and break the markup:

```
<? $test_output .= '<div class="complete-image cropped" style="background-image: url("'. $smallimage .'");">'."\n";?>
<!--                                                                          Here --^                            -->
```

Try using so:

```
<? $test_output .= "<div class=\"complete-image cropped\" style=\"background-image: url($smallimage);\">\n"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<? $test_output .= "<div class='complete-image cropped' style='background-image: url($smallimage);'>\n";?>
```